# How do I turn off the Steam Controller keyboard when playing Rocket League?

Tags: steam, rocket-league

I don't like the Steam controller keyboard coming up while I'm playing Rocket League. I have to play in Big Picture, as I'm on a Mac, and it doesn't handle my PS4 controller very well unless I do. Big Picture also wants to bring up the Steam controller keyboard anytime I want to chat, and I find it terribly distracting. How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Pysonix forums:

> If you'd like to get rid of this, go to Rocket League in your steam Library, then right click on it and go to properties.
>   At the bottom left you'll see 'Set launch options...'
>   open that and then add in -NoKeyboardUI
>   Press ok and play RL as you normally would. This will revert it back to the normal chat box
>
> -Dirkened on the Psyonix forums

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I just approved it. :D